# How to plot multiple UMAPs in a specified grid such as 6 x 3?

Tags: r, seurat

I am using the new Seurat 3 package to analyze single-cell sequencing data. I have merged 18 Seurat Objects and have saved the individual identifiers in the meta.data. When plotting out the 18 individual UMAPs using the `split.by` argument in the `DimPlot` function, it returns a plot in alphabetical order. It also plots 5 UMAPs on the first three rows and 3 on the last. I would like to plot a 6 by 3 grid and be able to order the UMAPs not alphabetically. Below is the command I used.

```
DimPlot(object = object, reduction = "umap", split.by = "orig.ident")
```

Comment: You better show a sample of your data to make it easier to reproduce your plots.

Comment: I have added the current plot.

Comment: Good. What about a subset of your data?

Comment: I don't know how to insert the tables.

Comment: The Seurat object is 13 Gb and it pulls data from about 3 different sections to make the UMAPs above, the UMAP cell embeddings, cluster IDs, and original cell identity.

Comment: So, it would be hard for us to help without having a sample data. I would advice you to take a look at documentation of the new Seurat package to investigate how you can go around this. Best of luck.

Comment: Ok. Thanks. I'll try to figure it out.

Comment: I figured it out! DimPlot(object = object, reduction = "umap", split.by = "orig.ident") + facet_wrap("orig.ident", nrow =6)

Comment: @KimberlyBurgess please post your comment as a solution below as **Answer**.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to go through ggplot2, there is an option inside `DimPlot()`:

```
library(Seurat)
pbmc_small = FindClusters(pbmc_small,resolution=1.2)
DimPlot(pbmc_small, split.by = "ident")
```

In this case we have 6 facets:

[image]

If we want 2 rows, say with an order 0,5,1,3,2,4 :

```
DimPlot(pbmc_small, split.by = "ident",ncol=3,order=rev(c(0,5,1,3,2,4)))
```

[image]